# eclipse terminates programs without an error

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse has begun terminating any program I try to run before it does anything. The only output is 4.12 printed to the console. It's not just one program with errors, I've tried running old programs that I know worked before but they all exit with 4.12 being printed out.

I tried downloading a new version of eclipse (Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)) but it hasn't really done anything. In the old version it was exiting everything with the code 4.11 so I've run out of ideas to get this to work again.

EDIT

I'm on a mac, using 64-bit. 
None of my programs run, I haven't just been leaving the main() empty.

I tried running from the command line and all my programs have changed type from .java to .class
The error I got in the command line was

> Class names, 'HelloWorld', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

The program running was just hello world.

Comment: Are you using the 32-bit version or 64-bit?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just returning from `main`?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for us to help you. Please read the "How to Ask" section of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Just edited it, I didn't have much information to go on, which is why my question is so vague, I tried to include as much as possible but I can't find anything else that's different about the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your programs via command line, outside of Eclipse, just to make sure it's not an IDE configuration. If still your programs fail, try to re-install your JRE/JDK.

if still the problem occurs - provide us with the exact command line errors.

Comment: I tried that and found out that all my programs have changed type from .java to .class. They show up the exact same in the IDE but the filename has been changed. Do you have any ideas how this has happened, and how I could undo it?

Comment: what you are explaining me sounds like a normal behavior - Java files get automatically compiled by Eclipse into .class files